# Unable to discover camera using AVCaptureDevice

Tags: swift, avcapturedevice

Here is my code:

```
if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.video) == .authorized {
    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(
        deviceTypes: [.builtInDualCamera],
        mediaType: AVMediaType.video,
        position: .back)
    let captureDevice = deviceDiscoverySession.devices.first
}
```

The result is empty array (deviceDiscoverySession.devices).
I am running on actual device (iPhone 6+ iOS 12.1.2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
// Find a camera with the specified AVCaptureDevicePosition, returning nil if one is not found
func cameraWithPosition(position: AVCaptureDevice.Position) -> AVCaptureDevice? {
    let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)
    for device in discoverySession.devices {
        if device.position == position {
            return device
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

---

```
if let newCamera = cameraWithPosition(position: .back) {
   //
}
```

Comment: Using .builtInWideAngleCamera does resolve the issue. But I wonder will this work for all iOS device models?

Comment: i used it and it doesn't break in old and new x generation , btw you can specify all possible values in that array

Comment: Thank you for your help , much appreciated.